# Setup global python environment properly with nix

Tags: python, macos, nix, nixos

I'm getting familiar with nix by using it instead of brew on my Mac. I like it pretty much so far, but there is an issue with python environment. I can't figure out how to configure it properly.

I'm using [powerline status](https://github.com/powerline/powerline), which is a python package itself, but also available as derivation (`nixpkgs.python37Packages.powerline`). So, I installed it together with python and some other packages:

```
# file: python.nix
with import <nixpkgs> {};
python3.withPackages (ps: with ps; [ pip pipenv powerline ipython ])
```

This is working as expected.

However, I'm also using some additional segments for powerline (ex. [powerline-gitstatus](https://github.com/jaspernbrouwer/powerline-gitstatus)), which are not available as derivations. So, I just installed them via `pip install --user ...`. And then set `PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.

This is also working.

Apart from that I need to have `awscli`, which is a python package and available as standalone derivation (not `nixpkgs.python37Packages.awscli`), so I can't install it as a part of my custom python derivation, as far as I understand.

I tried to get it with `nix-env -i awscli`, but it didn't work together with set `PYTHONPATH`.

I tried to get it with `pip install --user awscli`, but it didn't work also.

In both cases it crashed because of lack of dependencies or version incompatibilities.

So, my question is: how to setup global python environment properly with nix?

Comment: To moderators: I doubt that this question belongs to SO or to ServerFault, I'll move it if needed.

Comment: It's not very clear what the issue is, the question is rather vague. If you encountered any errors, it would be useful to include these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess following well-documented very convenient approach could help in your case also.

[How to consume python modules using pip in a virtualenv like I am used to on other Operating Systems ?](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/languages-frameworks/python.section.md#how-to-consume-python-modules-using-pip-in-a-virtualenv-like-i-am-used-to-on-other-operating-systems-)

10.09.2020 Update:
[Developing Python with Poetry & Poetry2nix: Reproducible flexible Python environments](https://www.tweag.io/blog/2020-08-12-poetry2nix/) describes an other working with python on NixOS approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. So far I managed to do some necessary stuff with pypi2nix, but it's not very convenient still.

Comment: [pypi2nix](https://github.com/garbas/pypi2nix) is a tool to generate Nix expressions for Python packages. While usage of `pip` inside of `nix-shell` is a handy and more powerful approach to setup python environment on NixOS.